# Getting the name of a resource from code behind

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBlock with the following xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="typeTextBlock" Text="{DynamicResource TypeString}" ></TextBlock>
```

I want to get the string "TypeString" in code behind and assign it to a variable of type string. How can I achieve that?

```
string typeResource = ???
```

Now typeResource variable should be equal to the string "TypeString"

NOTE:
I don't want to get the value of the resource, but the name of the resource:

```
 "TypeString": "Type",
```

I don't want the string "Type", but the string: "TypeString".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string typeResource = Application.Current.Resources["TypeString"] as string;
```

**Update**: hopefully now I get the question correctly:

```
string typeResource = typeTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).ResolvedSourcePropertyName;
```

**Update 2**: Just came across another method:

```
string typeResource = BindingOperations.GetBinding(typeTextBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty).Path.Path;
```

Comment: No, this will give me the value of the resource.
Not the string - "TypeString"

Comment: @DimaK Then you have to specify more details in your question what you want. Please read a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @mami `string typeResource = typeTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).ResolvedSourcePropertyName;` returns null exception

Comment: It works for me. Of course it can throw a null exception if your typeTextBlock is null. If you mean it returns null, then your binding is probably not working.